# Working with ST and Data.UnionFind.ST

Tags: haskell, data-structures

I'm trying to use the [UnionFind package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/union-find-0.2/docs/Data-UnionFind-ST.html) because I need this structure for my exercise (clustering nodes, numbered 1 .. 500) (notwithstanding this [blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/12/31/haskell-an-impressively-non-performant-union-find/) suggesting that it does not help) and to learn about ST.

My first problem is that the package does not seem to have a function for bulk loading initial data. I therefore created the following (based on the foldST example in http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad/ST) to initialise the data structure, but I can't find a convincing way to call `initialClustering` and there is no easy way to see whether data structure was created.

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.UnionFind.ST as UF

type Start = Int
--Union-find: clusters of Nodes
type Cluster = UF.Point [Start]

main = do
    let 
        -- next line is clearly wrong but can't find another way to run function
        iCluster = initialClustering [1..500]
    print $ UF.repr [5]             -- i
    print $ UF.repr (UF.Pt [5])     -- ii
    return ()

initialClustering :: [t] -> ()
initialClustering xs = runST $ do
    forM_ xs $ \x -> do
        UF.fresh [x]
```

But I am doing something wrong as compilation fails with i)

```
Couldn't match expected type `UF.Point s0 a0'
            with actual type `[t1]'
In the first argument of `UF.repr', namely `[5]'
```

and ii)

```
 Not in scope: data constructor `UF.Point'
```

This reflects a more fundamental lack of understanding about ST and the newtype used to create the UnionFind.ST library.

Comment: It would help if you posted the entire program and the entire error message.  There seems to be some problem with your installation of `union-find`.

Comment: I don't get the same errors you do. Are you sure you pasted the version of the code you have currently?

Comment: ...additionally, your code seems to be based on severe misconceptions about how to use `ST` in general and this library in particular. I fear any complete answer to this question is going to risk creating yet another monad tutorial. I recommend that you look at one of the many existing tutorials before taking another shot at this code. For example, I enjoyed [All About Monads](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/All_about_monads) and [You Could Have Invented Monads! (And Maybe You Already Have.)](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html).

Comment: @DanielWagner Unfortunately i) all the beginner tutorials focus on Maybe and IO, perhaps with State too, and I've written code with each of those monads ii) the docs for this library contain no examples of their use

Comment: @SimonH: The types are clear and provide a documentation. `ST s` is a monad. That's all what you need to know. Also, you need to store those points somewhere.

Comment: @Zeta I sense that 'store' is an important clue here, as I note that this library calls itself an implementation of an 'algorithm', whereas on Coursera it was described a 'data structure'. But not a clue I know how to use.  Can't find any implementations of this library online, so I think it makes little sense for me to try to be the first.

Comment: @SimonH: It assumes that you know a little bit about refs. Have a look at STRef or IORef.

Comment: Thanks @Zeta, indeed I do not know what a Ref is.  But I was able to get a solution using this implementation of UnionFind (http://kwangyulseo.com/2014/01/30/implementing-union-find-algorithms-in-haskell/) as it came with its own data structure and an example of code using it.  I've learnt a bit about Monads along the way but can't claim to be comfortable yet!

Comment: Just found this -  http://tel.github.io/2014/07/12/mutable_algorithms_in_immutable_languges_part_1/ - which is really helpful